# PHP xPath with multiple not conditions

Tags: php, xpath

I want to select all the images but exclude the images under `id="adminbar"` and the images start with or contain `src="data:image`

```
<div id="wpadminbar" class="nojq nojs">
<img src="example.com/img">
<img src="example.com/img">
</div>
<img class="d-none d-lg-block" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%200%200'%3E%3C/svg%3E">
<img src="example/img.jpg">
<img src="example/img.png">
```

i tried this but it just excludes the images under `id="adminbar"`

`//img[not(ancestor::div[@id="wpadminbar"])]`

how to add **not** again to exclude all the `img` contain or startwith `src="data:image`

Comment: Your are using 2 id's: `wpadminbar` and `adminbar`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add another predicate to the end of the expression, which will filter the results a second time. In the second predicate, use the `starts-with` function to check if the `@src` starts with `data:image`:

```xml
//img[not(ancestor::div[@id='wpadminbar'])][not(starts-with(@src, 'data:image'))]
```